# How to enforce set -o pipefail on failing first command in pipe

Tags: pipe

I am trying export data from a postgres database to a file in bash. But I would like to make sure that the file is only overwritten if the connection to the database doesn't fail (i.e. I get some data back)

Tried the use the *pipefail* option, however if the first command fails with an error (host doesn't exist for example), the cat command still executes and generates an empty file (wiping out the last good content from it which I would like to prevent).
In the example below, myhost is invalid host, so the psql command would simply fail.

So the larger question is how to make sure that when pipefail is set, subsequent commands are not executed when the first command fails.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail

PG_HOST=myhost

psql $PG_HOST -At -F$'\t' -c "SELECT * FROM mytable" | cat > /tmp/mytable.txt
```

Comment: I don't think that's what pipefail does. If I may sidestep the direct question for the overall goal, what about piping the psql output to a temporary file and renaming the file only if it was successful? `psql ... > temp && mv temp mytable` ?

Comment: on a separate side note, it appears that psql has a "--output=filename" option; does that clobber the output file if the overall command fails?

Comment: Pipes run in parallel; their very nature make it difficult to stop the truncation of `/tmp/mytable.sh`. Note that that will happen irrespective of the `cat` running successfully - the file is truncated, then set up as the output for `cat`, and then `cat` is started. Maybe you should look into `sponge` from moreutils.

Comment: The psql is just one use case, understand that I can achieve the desired output in multiple steps. Trying to understand how pipe behaves stream data between 2 systems elegantly.
An other use case would be to take the output of the first command from STDOUT and pipe it into an other Postgres server that would copy the dat from STDIN. 
psql -H host1 -c "select * from mytable" | psql -H host2 -c "TRUNCATE TABLE mytable; COPY mytable FROM STDIN"
 
The problem is that if the first command fails the 2nd still runs, truncates the table and copies the empty stream.

Comment: `pipefail` doesn't abort if there is an error; it merely means that an error at any point in a pipe chain will be preserved for the exit code even if the final command is successful.  `set -o pipefail; if ! /bin/false | /bin/yes; then echo foo; fi` will indeed output `foo` even though `yes` returns `0`.  What you might really be looking for is `trap 'echo "Something went awry"; exit 1' ERR`.

Answer (score 4):

`set -o pipefail -o errexit` does prevent subsequent commands from being executed, but that doesn't help you, because you are not trying to prevent a *subsequent* command from being executed. In a pipeline `producer | consumer`, the `producer` and `consumer` commands execute *in parallel*. You can't prevent `consumer` from starting if `producer` fails because barring a freak timing accident, it has already started.

If the only two possibilities are “`consumer` succeeds and produces non-empty output” and “`consumer` fails and produces no output”, you can use [`ifne` from Joey Hess's moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).

```
producer | ifne consumer
```

I don't think that works in your use case though — there could happen to be no matching rows (false negative, and you get stale data), the database connection could be lost in the middle (false positive, and you get truncated data).

If you need to know whether the producer succeeded, then you need to wait until it's finished before starting the consumer. And since the consumer isn't around yet, something needs to store the output.

If the output doesn't contain null bytes, ends in one and only one newline character and isn't overly large, you can store it in a shell variable.

```
output=$(producer); producer_status=$?
if [ "$producer_status" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo >&2 "Producer failed with status $producer_status"
  exit "$producer_status"
fi
printf '%s\n' "$output" | consumer
```

In zsh and a few other shells including ksh93 and bash, that last line can be simplified to `consumer <<<"$output"`.

Note that command substitution strips trailing newlines. If trailing empty lines are relevant, a workaround is to change the first line to

```
output=$(producer; ret=$?; echo .; exit "$?")
producer_status=$? output=${output%?}
```

`$output` will then contain the full output including the trailing newline characters if any. Then use `printf %s "$output"` instead of `printf '%s\n' "$output"` to feed it to the `consumer`.

If the output is potentially too large or may contain null bytes, store it in a temporary file.

Comment: what if there's multiple consecutive commands and I want to fail the pipe on any of them, but I don't want to check each? There's no straightforward option/command?

Comment: @Xerus You mean `a | b | c` and you don't even want to run `b` if `a` fails? Then a pipe is the wrong construct. `a`, `b` and `c` run in parallel, so by the time `a` finishes, the others have already started.

Comment: yeah, I guessed so. I have now broken down the pipe.
Actually, this ifne would be a perfect match, but I don't want to add dependencies and I couldn't find its source code on that site to potentially embed it

Answer (score 0):

As DopeGhoti said, *`pipefail` ... merely means that error at any point in a pipe chain will be preserved for the exit code* [of a pipeline].

To cause the script to exit on error, use `set -e`.

To prevent creation of the file, create a temporary one and rename it on success, viz:

```
set -e 
psql $PG_HOST -At -F$'\t' -c \
    "SELECT * FROM mytable"  >  /tmp/mytable.txt~
                          # ^^^ cf. Useless Use of Cat
mv /tmp/mytable.txt~ /tmp/mytable.txt
```

I always use **make** for this sort of thing, because it stops on error and lets me build restartable pipelines.